# Given a sentence such as following, can I print it vertically (i.e., one character on each line)?

Tags: python

And can I modify my answer above so that my program will stop printing after it prints the first "!"?
For example: `'I never want to say goodbye to you! No!'`

```
I
never
want
to
say
goodbye
to
you
```

Comment: One character or one word per line ?

Comment: Please read the question and title... title says one character per line and in the output it is 1 word per line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considering you want the output of the form:

```
I
never
want
to
say
goodbye
to
you
```

Try this:

```
a = "I never want to say goodbye to you! No!"
a = a.split(" ")
for word in a:
  print(word, end='\n')
  if "!" in word:
    break
```

But if you need one character per line, you can try this:

```
a = list("I never want to say goodbye to you! No!")

for i in a:
  print(i, end='\n')
  if i == "!":
    break
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to print one character per line, @Prashant Kumar has answered it.

if you want to print one word per line, you can use this.

```
str="I never want to say goodbye to you! No!"
string=str.split()
for word in string:
    if '!' not in word:
        print(word)
    else:
        print(word[:-1])
        break
```